# How to access a device by hostname through Jetpack/MiFi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, android, mifi

I have a Verizon Jetpack Mi-Fi device, which behaves as a wireless router. Connected to it are three clients:

1. A Windows laptop whose hostname is `windows1`. IP address from the Jetpack is `192.168.1.2`.
2. A Windows laptop whose hostname is `windows2`. IP address from the Jetpack is `192.168.1.3`.
3. A **non-rooted** Android tablet. IP address from the Jetpack is 192.168.1.4.

I have a web server running on `windows1` and listening on port 80. If I open a web browser on `windows2` and navigate to `http://windows1`, the web server home page loads properly. If I open a web browser on the tablet and navigate to `http://windows1`, the web server home page does not load, and I get the following error:

> **This webpage is not available**
>
> ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

On the tablet, if I navigate instead to `http://192.168.1.2`, the web server home page loads properly.

I would very much like to access `http://windows1` from the Android tablet by hostname, not by IP address, just like I can do from `windows2`. What is a simple way to achieve that, if it is even possible?

**UPDATE**

I do need to access content on `http://windows1` from Chrome running on the Android tablet. I also need to access `http://windows1` from another app that is not a web browser itself but consumes web services that run on `windows1`. Those web services provide responses that tell the app to get other resources via absolute URLs on `windows1`. Changing my services to use IP addresses exclusively would be a very undesirable workaround for multiple reasons. Therefore, I'm asking for a solution in which the Android device makes a DNS request for `windows1` and the correct IP address is returned.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is that Windows uses multicast DNS to advertise servers on the local network and the default DNS system the Android browser uses does not resolve mDNS for some reason.

Android does have mDNS support that apps can use though, so one solution may be to use a browser app that supports mDNS such as [ZeroConf Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.melloware.zeroconf&hl=en). Your call whether that’s more convenient than entering the IP address.

Comment: Thank you for the useful information. You used some terms that have pointed me in the right direction. However, ZeroConf Browser simply shows what web servers and other resources it can find on the network. It is not a web browser and does not allow a web browser to find those resources by hostname. Moreover, ZeroConf Browser isn't actually finding my laptop's web server; even if it did, it wouldn't solve the issue I have. I'm going to update my question to clarify what I need to do. Again, thank you for the helpful information.